# How does SAP BusinessObjects make calls to a Hana Database?

Tags: sapui5, business-intelligence, hana, business-objects

New to SAP BusinessObjects in general. I'm trying to get an understanding of how specifically BusinessObjects can make calls to a database like HANA. And when it (BusinessObjects) does make a call to the database, how can you expose the data to a frontend application like SAPUI5 or Design Studio?

For comparison purposes, I know that the SAP XS Engine can make calls to the database using OData which we can then use to store data in a model. This much is not clear for BO, can anyone provide some insight into the details of how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

**Connection/deployment of [SAP Business Objects Design Studio](https://help.sap.com/bodesignstudio_re) in regards to SAP HANA:**

1. **Local:** If design studio is saved in your local computer, then connection to SAP HANA is done through a ODBC connection using HANA Client Software.
2. **SAP NetWeaver:** If design studio is stored in SAP BW, Connecting to HANA is not possible.
3. **BI Platform:** If design studio application is saved in the BI Platform, the connection to SAP HANA is done through an **OLAP connection** created in the Central Management Console.
4. **SAP HANA**: If design studio application is saved in the HANA repository, connections are only possible to the host HANA system.

[Developer Guide to Design Studio](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/AAD16/en/ds_16SP04_dev_guide_en.pdf)

Comment: could you further elaborate on #3? What are OLAP connections? What is the role of a Central Management Console, thanks :)

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2013/07/12/businessobjects-design-studio-11-setting-up-an-sso-connection-to-sap-hana/